# Grouping by date stored as varchar2

Tags: sql, oracle, date, varchar2

I am trying to run the following query:

```
SELECT TAB.week_end, 
    COUNT(TAB.id)
FROM (
        SELECT C.week_end,              
            C.ID   
        FROM my_table C     
        WHERE C.week_end IS NOT NULL
    ) TAB
GROUP BY TAB.week_end, TAB.id
```

Expected result:

```
week_end  id
2016-01   45000
2016-02   61000
2016-03   59000
```

What I'm getting is:

```
week_end  id
2016-01   1
2016-01   1
2016-02   1
2016-02   1
```

Now I know the difficulties when grouping by date. But in my case the date is already stored as `varchar2`. Anybody can help me out here?

Comment: Simply `GROUP BY TAB.week_end`?

Comment: Remove Tab.id from group by

Answer (score 3):

Use following:

```
 SELECT TAB.week_end, COUNT(TAB.id)
 FROM (SELECT C.week_end,              
         C.ID   
 FROM my_table C     
 WHERE C.week_end IS NOT NULL) TAB
 GROUP BY TAB.week_end
```

If the two tables are the same u can achieve as follows:

```
 SELECT C.week_end, COUNT(C.id)  
 FROM my_table C     
 WHERE C.week_end IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY C.week_end
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove Tab.id from group by solves it